# Publishing progress in async task

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Is there any way to publish progress from doInBackground() to onProgressUpdate() without using publishProgress()?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, no. `onProgressUpdate()` is only called in response to a call to `publishProgress()`.

Note that `AsyncTask` is likely to be marked as deprecated with the release of Android 11.